# Sylius seems to call non-existent method

Tags: php, symfony, curl, state-machine, sylius

Ok so I'm using Symfony + Sylius. I've noticed that defined in the routing for checkout (checkout.yml) is the following:

```
sylius_shop_checkout_complete:
    path: /complete
    methods: [GET, PUT]
    defaults:
        _controller: sylius.controller.order:updateAction 
        _sylius:
            event: summary
            flash: false
            template: SyliusShopBundle:Checkout:complete.html.twig
            repository:
                method: find
                arguments: [expr:service('sylius.context.cart').getCart()]
            state_machine:
                graph: sylius_order_checkout
                transition: complete
            redirect:
                route: sylius_shop_order_pay
                parameters:
                    paymentId: expr:service('sylius.context.cart').getCart().getLastNewPayment().getId()
            form:
                type: sylius_checkout_complete
                options:
                    validation_groups: 'sylius_checkout_complete'
```

Seems pretty straight forward no? Yes. However, upon looking for the updateAction method in the Order Controller, it simply doesn't exist. I know the code is working as I can order products from my site successfully however, I was hoping to hook some CURL commands into updateAction and render some responses in the template but I simply can't find the method?!

What is this madness?

Here's the Order Controller in case you need proof:

```
<?php

/*
 * This file is part of the Sylius package.
 *
 * (c) Paweł Jędrzejewski
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Controller;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use FOS\RestBundle\View\View;
use Payum\Core\Registry\RegistryInterface;
use Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Controller\RequestConfiguration;
use Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Controller\ResourceController;
use Sylius\Component\Order\Context\CartContextInterface;
use Sylius\Component\Order\Model\OrderInterface;
use Sylius\Component\Order\SyliusCartEvents;
use Sylius\Component\Resource\ResourceActions;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\GenericEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;
use Webmozart\Assert\Assert;

class OrderController extends ResourceController
{
    /**
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function summaryAction(Request $request)
    {
        $configuration = $this->requestConfigurationFactory->create($this->metadata, $request);

        $cart = $this->getCurrentCart();

        if (!$configuration->isHtmlRequest()) {
            return $this->viewHandler->handle($configuration, View::create($cart));
        }

        $form = $this->resourceFormFactory->create($configuration, $cart);

        $view = View::create()
            ->setTemplate($configuration->getTemplate('summary.html'))
            ->setData([
                'cart' => $cart,
                'form' => $form->createView(),
            ])
        ;

        return $this->viewHandler->handle($configuration, $view);
    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function saveAction(Request $request)
    {
        $configuration = $this->requestConfigurationFactory->create($this->metadata, $request);

        $this->isGrantedOr403($configuration, ResourceActions::UPDATE);
        $resource = $this->getCurrentCart();

        $form = $this->resourceFormFactory->create($configuration, $resource);

        if (in_array($request->getMethod(), ['POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH'], true) && $form->submit($request, !$request->isMethod('PATCH'))->isValid()) {
            $resource = $form->getData();

            $event = $this->eventDispatcher->dispatchPreEvent(ResourceActions::UPDATE, $configuration, $resource);

            if ($event->isStopped() && !$configuration->isHtmlRequest()) {
                throw new HttpException($event->getErrorCode(), $event->getMessage());
            }
            if ($event->isStopped()) {
                $this->flashHelper->addFlashFromEvent($configuration, $event);

                return $this->redirectHandler->redirectToResource($configuration, $resource);
            }

            if ($configuration->hasStateMachine()) {
                $this->stateMachine->apply($configuration, $resource);
            }

            $this->eventDispatcher->dispatchPostEvent(ResourceActions::UPDATE, $configuration, $resource);

            if (!$configuration->isHtmlRequest()) {
                return $this->viewHandler->handle($configuration, View::create(null, Response::HTTP_NO_CONTENT));
            }

            $this->getEventDispatcher()->dispatch(SyliusCartEvents::CART_CHANGE, new GenericEvent($resource));
            $this->manager->flush();

            $this->flashHelper->addSuccessFlash($configuration, ResourceActions::UPDATE, $resource);

            return $this->redirectHandler->redirectToResource($configuration, $resource);
        }

        if (!$configuration->isHtmlRequest()) {
            return $this->viewHandler->handle($configuration, View::create($form, Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST));
        }

        $view = View::create()
            ->setData([
                'configuration' => $configuration,
                $this->metadata->getName() => $resource,
                'form' => $form->createView(),
                'cart' => $resource,
            ])
            ->setTemplate($configuration->getTemplate(ResourceActions::UPDATE . '.html'))
        ;

        return $this->viewHandler->handle($configuration, $view);
    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function thankYouAction(Request $request)
    {
        $configuration = $this->requestConfigurationFactory->create($this->metadata, $request);

        $orderId = $request->getSession()->get('sylius_order_id', null);

        if (null === $orderId) {
            return $this->redirectHandler->redirectToRoute(
                $configuration,
                $configuration->getParameters()->get('after_failure[route]', 'sylius_shop_homepage', true),
                $configuration->getParameters()->get('after_failure[parameters]', [], true)
            );
        }

        $request->getSession()->remove('sylius_order_id');
        $order = $this->repository->find($orderId);
        Assert::notNull($order);

        $view = View::create()
            ->setData([
                'order' => $order
            ])
            ->setTemplate($configuration->getParameters()->get('template'))
        ;

        return $this->viewHandler->handle($configuration, $view);
    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function clearAction(Request $request)
    {
        $configuration = $this->requestConfigurationFactory->create($this->metadata, $request);

        $this->isGrantedOr403($configuration, ResourceActions::DELETE);
        $resource = $this->getCurrentCart();

        $event = $this->eventDispatcher->dispatchPreEvent(ResourceActions::DELETE, $configuration, $resource);

        if ($event->isStopped() && !$configuration->isHtmlRequest()) {
            throw new HttpException($event->getErrorCode(), $event->getMessage());
        }
        if ($event->isStopped()) {
            $this->flashHelper->addFlashFromEvent($configuration, $event);

            return $this->redirectHandler->redirectToIndex($configuration, $resource);
        }

        $this->repository->remove($resource);
        $this->eventDispatcher->dispatchPostEvent(ResourceActions::DELETE, $configuration, $resource);

        if (!$configuration->isHtmlRequest()) {
            return $this->viewHandler->handle($configuration, View::create(null, Response::HTTP_NO_CONTENT));
        }

        $this->flashHelper->addSuccessFlash($configuration, ResourceActions::DELETE, $resource);

        return $this->redirectHandler->redirectToIndex($configuration, $resource);
    }

    /**
     * @param RequestConfiguration $configuration
     *
     * @return RedirectResponse
     */
    protected function redirectToCartSummary(RequestConfiguration $configuration)
    {
        if (null === $configuration->getParameters()->get('redirect')) {
            return $this->redirectHandler->redirectToRoute($configuration, $this->getCartSummaryRoute());
        }

        return $this->redirectHandler->redirectToRoute($configuration, $configuration->getParameters()->get('redirect'));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getCartSummaryRoute()
    {
        return 'sylius_cart_summary';
    }

    /**
     * @return OrderInterface
     */
    protected function getCurrentCart()
    {
        return $this->getContext()->getCart();
    }

    /**
     * @return CartContextInterface
     */
    protected function getContext()
    {
        return $this->get('sylius.context.cart');
    }

    /**
     * @return EventDispatcherInterface
     */
    protected function getEventDispatcher()
    {
        return $this->container->get('event_dispatcher');
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT

```
$ app/console debug:router sylius_shop_checkout_complete
    +--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | Property     | Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
    +--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | Route Name   | sylius_shop_checkout_complete                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
    | Path         | /checkout/complete                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        |
    | Path Regex   | #^/checkout/complete$#s                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
    | Host         | ANY                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       |
    | Host Regex   |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
    | Scheme       | ANY                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       |
    | Method       | GET|PUT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
    | Requirements | NO CUSTOM                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 |
    | Class        | Symfony\Component\Routing\Route                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
    | Defaults     | _controller: sylius.controller.order:updateAction                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
    |              | _sylius: array ('event' => 'summary','flash' => false,'template' => 'SyliusShopBundle:Checkout:complete.html.twig','repository' => array ('method' => 'find','arguments' => array (0 => 'expr:service(\'sylius.context.cart\').getCart()',),),'state_machine' => array ('graph' => 'sylius_order_checkout','transition' => 'complete',),'redirect' => array ('route' => 'sylius_shop_order_pay','parameters' => array ('paymentId' => 'expr:service(\'sylius.context.cart\').getCart().getLastNewPayment().getId()',),),'form' => array ('type' => 'sylius_checkout_complete','options' => array ('validation_groups' => 'sylius_checkout_complete',),),) |
    | Options      | compiler_class: Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCompiler                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
    +--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: What does `bin/console debug:router sylius_shop_checkout_complete` say?

Comment: @AlisterBulman question updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sylius is very dynamic, and a good portion appears to be generated into the container at build time from the configurations which even allows for altering the workflows of how the data moves through the system.

`sylius.controller.order` is an example of that. The `Order` model, controller, and repository are passed into `ResourceController.php`, which is where the updateAction is. The same actions, with different parameters are used for other data models as well.